# More granular limits in Mongo aggregate calls?

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I have a query I would like to run on Mongo. Essentially it looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('termStatistics').aggregate(
    { $filter: { "kind": 0 } },
    {
        $group:
        {
            "_id": "$termId",
            "count": {$sum: NumberLong(1)}
        }
    },
    { $sort: {"count": -1} },
    { $limit: 100 }
)
```

This gets the count of each `termId` and gives me the top 100 of them. However, I've got to run this same query for each value of `kind`, of which there are several, because the user wants the top 100 for each category. I'd like to avoid going back to mongo several times for a single query (the actual filter also does some user-specific filtering, so it's not reasonable to cache the results).

Is it possible to combine all these into a single aggregation call? Some kind of "limit per value of kind" or something?

*Edit*: Here are some sample documents. These are a little dumb, but it's hard to post thousands of documents with any interest to them....  Suppose I've got `n` copies of these (with varying `_id`s) for each `n` between 1 and 1000:

```
{ kind: 0, termId: n }
```

Plus I've got `n` of these, for each `n` between 1 and 100:

```
{ kind: 1, termId: n }
```

What I want is the top 100 `termId` for each kind. For `kind: 0` this would be `[{ _id: 1000, count: 1000 }, ...{ _id: 901, count: 901 }]` and for `kind: 1` this would be `[{ _id: 200, count: 200 }, ..., { _id: 101, count: 101 }]`.

This is easy to do but it takes two aggregate calls (see above). It would be nice to do one aggregate call and get something *like* the following:

```
[
    { kind: 0, data: [{ _id: 1000, count: 1000 }, ...{ _id: 901, count: 901 }]},
    { kind: 1, data: [{ _id: 200, count: 200 }, ...{ _id: 101, count: 101 }]},
]
```

If we just raise the limit to 200, we won't get anything from `kind: 1` because there are enough common `termId`s from `kind: 0`, so I'd need some other kind of limit, or some really clever use of it.

Hope that's more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do but you could try grouping on the "kind" field AND the term instead of using $match or $filter on it first.

Something like:

```
db.getCollection('termStatistics').aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "kind": "$kind",
                "term": "$termId"
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: {"count": -1} },
    { $limit: 100 }
)
```

Comment: This would still return only 100 documents, though. I need essentially 600 documents -- 100 for each value of kind. But if I set the limit to 600, I'll probably get (e.g.) 500 from the most popular kind, and thus not enough from the rest.

Comment: Can you post a few sample documents and what you want your output to be?